# Partition function of empty state set?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition, partition-function

The partition function of a state space $X$, is:

$Z=\sum_{x\in X} \exp(-E(x))$

where $E(x)$ is the energy of the state $x\in X$. By this formula it seems that if $X$ is empty, $Z=0$. Does this make sense? Is there a sensible way in which the partition function can be defined when the state space is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition function is a measure of the number of microstates corresponding to a given macrostate. It basically is a measure of the volume occupied by a macrostate in configuration space. If the configuration space itself is empty, the partition function will of course be $0$.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just wanted to be sure this was the accepted definition.